# Escape batch pseudo-variable

Tags: command-line, batch

I need to call a batch file with a command I want it to execute. This command contains the %cd% pseudo-variable, which expands to the current directory. Say, I want to run `test "echo %cd%"`. The problem is that `%cd%` expands before `test` is called.

Normally, you can escape a variable by doubling the percent signs, but this does not seem to apply to pseudo-variables. For instance, `echo %%ProgramFiles%%` will print `%ProgramFiles%`, but `echo %%errorlevel%%` will print `%0%`. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The general-purpose escape character in Windows Command Prompt — the analog of `\` in the rest of the universe — is caret (`^`).  Try “`^%cd^%`”.

(Edit)

… and then,

```
echo %1 > temp.bat
call temp.bat
del temp.bat
```

Yes, it’s terribly ugly, and there really ought to be a better way.  Well, I can’t find it.

Comment: Ah, but now `test "echo ^%cd^%"` prints `%cd%` instead of the current directory. What I need is for the pseudo-variable to be preserved when I pass it to the script, but expanded inside.

Comment: OK, I’ve edited my answer to address that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having much luck without getting CALL involved, either.  With this test.bat:

```
@%*
```

invoking **test.bat call echo ^%cd^%** works as expected.  Or, putting the CALL inside test.bat:

```
@CALL %*
```

and invoking **test.bat echo ^%cd^%** works.  (This is safer anyhow, since if test.bat is getting called from another script, then passing a script to it won't run the risk of exiting prematurely.)

I suppose which works better for you (or if either can be made to work at all) depends on the specifics of your scenario.